# Using "but" with modals

Tags: modal-verbs, negation, conditionals

Friend: John, can you come to the party tonight?

1. John: Sorry, no. I **could** come, **but** my mum is very ill and I have to take care of her.
2. John: Sorry, no. I **could've** come, **but** my mum is very ill and I have to take care of her.
3. John: Sorry, no. I **would** come, **but** my mum is very ill and I have to take care of her.
4. John: Sorry, no. I **would've** come, **but** my mum is very ill and I have to take care of her.

Q: Can I use the word "but" in this way with the modal verbs "could" and "would" to completely negate what has been said in the previous clause, instead of using any conditional markers like "if", "provided that", "otherwise" etc?

Comment: Yes, it is normal to use _but_ in this context.

Comment: The word ***but*** in your examples doesn't necessarily imply that whatever precedes it (a present or future action) ***won''t / can't*** happen. But the "Perfect" forms *could / would **have** [done something]* both imply that the action referred to ***didn't*** happen (and it was only a possibility ***in the past*** anyway; it's meaningless to ask whether it might happen in the present or future).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 3 is correct:

> I **would** come, **but** my mum is very ill and I have to take care of her.

"Would" indicates your personal *intention*, so this means that you would personally choose to go, but there is a reason that prevents you.

The others need attention, for various reasons.

> I could come, but my mum is very ill and I have to take care of her.

"Could" can be used to indicate possibility, but when we use it with "but" it is usually to introduce a *condition*, not to negate it, for example:

> I could come, but I'll have to find someone to look after my mum.

---

> I could've come, but my mum is very ill and I have to take care of her.

"Could *have*" doesn't work with a *future* (or hypothetical) event, only a past event, for example:

> I **could've gone**, but my mum **was** very ill and I **had** to take care of her.

---

> I would've come, but my mum is very ill and I have to take care of her.

Same reason as above - "would have" is for referring to past events.

Comment: So in sentence (1), "but" *partially* negates it. What if I rewrite sentence (1) like this: *I **could** come **if** my mum were not ill.*" Would this be correct?

Comment: @Mr.X Not really, you're not thinking about the tense again. "Could" is future... but "were" is is present. You could instead say "I *can* come if my mum *isn't* ill", or "I could come if mum gets better".

Comment: So these sentences, too, would not work: 1) *If my leg **were** not injured, I **could** come with you to the market* 2) *If my leg **were** not injured, I **could** be playing with them **now**.* Am I right?

Comment: @Mr.X Actually those *do* work... because a past injury can still affect you now. Saying "my leg *was* injured" is referring to an event in which your leg was hurt, but some people do idiomatically say "my leg *is* injured" to mean they still have an injury.

Comment: Is it because, in the above sentences, I've temporarily lost my **ability** to properly walk, and so using "could" sounds good in them and not in *I **could** come if my mum **were not** ill*?

Comment: @Mr.X That's it, basically.

Comment: Thank you very much! Last question: Can I use "might" like this: *I **might** come if my mum **were** not ill* in the sense that ***maybe** I would come if my mum **were not** ill*?